# How to get this effect?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to reach one point using div's and bootstrap. It should be in one line number of points and smaller information about points and in second area should be bootstrap icon and again information about icon.
My code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center-block">
      <div class="col-md-5" style="padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px; ">
          <i class="pull-left h2"><h2>72</h2></i> TWOJE PUNKTY
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7" style="padding: 0px">
          <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-2x pull-left"></i> WYRÓZNIENIE SZYBKI BILL
      </div>
      <br>
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th><h2>72</h2></th>
          <th>you points</th>
          <th><i class="fa fa-trophy fa-2x pull-left"></i></th>
          <th>fastL</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This funny should be a boostrap icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code and you can adjust `col-` class according to you

```css
.flex-div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-text {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 34px;
}
.icon-text h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center-block row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-xs-6 flex-div">
        <div class="icon-text">
          <h2>72</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="info-text">
          TWOJE PUNKTY<br/>
          WYRÓZNIENIE SZYBKI BILL
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-6 flex-div ">
        <div class="icon-text">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="info-text">
          Your Achivement Reached
        </div>
      </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :-)

Comment: Glad to helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that effect using something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pukpnkov/4/).

HTML:

```
<div class="points"> 72 </div>
<div class="points-details">
Your 
points
</div>

<div class="icon">+</div>
<div class="icon-details">
Your 
Achievment
Reached
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.points{
  display: inline-block;
}
.points-details{
  display: inline-block;
}
.icon{
 margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.icon-details{
  display: inline-block;
}
```